# Como usar informações do back-end no front-end com Python e Django?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

No meu código `Python` eu crio um objeto chamado `status` da seguinte maneira:

Em forms/status.py

```
class StatusForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Status
        fields = ('status', 'posicao')
        widget = {
            'status': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'posicao': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    }
        labels = {
            'status': _('Descrição'),
            'posicao': _('Posição da coluna na navegação'),
    }
```

Em models/status.py

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    posicao = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Status"
        permissions = (
            ("view_status", "Can view status"),
        )
```

E o seguinte código em views/status.py

```
class AdicionarStatusView(AdicionarOutrosBaseView):
    form_class = StatusForm
    model = Status
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cadastro:addstatusview')
    permission_codename = 'add_status'


 class StatusView(CustomListView):
    model = Status
    template_name = 'cadastro/status_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_status'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cadastro:listastatusview')
    permission_codename = 'view_status'
```

Em templates/cadastro/status_list.html, onde fica a tabela para eu ver os `status` que já foram criados, faço o seguinte:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="lista-database" >
            <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>#ID</th>
                    <th>Descrição</th>
                    <th>Posição na Navegação</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>   
                    {% for status in all_status %}
                        <td>{{status.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{status.status}}</td>
                        <td>{{status.posicao_navegacao}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
               </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Ou seja, no meu código `html` com a tabela de toda a lista de `status`, para poder acessar o `id` de `status` basta eu informar `{{status.id}}` dentro de um `loop`. Agora eu preciso acessar essa mesma informação em outro arquivo `html`, chamado `index.html`, para isso tentei fazer dessa forma dentro de `views/status.py`:

```
class StatusListEmNavegacaoView(CustomListView):
    model = StatusVenda
    template_name = 'crm/navegacao/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_status'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('crm:navegacaoview')
    permission_codename = 'view_status'
```

Mas ao criar o `loop` dentro do arquivo `index.html` não estou tento resultado nenhum.

Provavelmente estou fazendo de forma incorreta. Na tabela de `status` está funcionando, porém em outro arquivo não. Todas os `import`estão corretos. Qual a maneira adequada para que eu possa acessar meu objeto `status` em outro arquivo `html`?

Answer (score 0):

A sua classe `StatusListEmNavegacaoView` está importando o model `StatusVenda` e não o modelo `Status`. Ou seja o objeto disponível em seu template será o StatusVendas e não o Status. Pelo que percebo você precisa ter dois objetos em seu template.

Para você obter todos os objetos Status você vai sobrescrever o método `get_context_data`. Com ele você cria objetos que ficam disponíveis no seu template.

```
from .models import Status

class StatusListEmNavegacaoView(CustomListView):
   model = StatusVenda
   template_name = 'crm/navegacao/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'all_status'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('crm:navegacaoview')
   permission_codename = 'view_status'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['status'] = Status.objects.all()
      return context
```

Com isso você vai ter a variável status disponível no seu template, em seu caso `index.html`. Então é só você fazer o loop no template

```
{% for s in status %}
   <td>{{s.id}}</td>
   <td>{{s.status}}</td>
   <td>{{s.posicao}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```